# convert date to date serial

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert a date (date type) into a long. 
This long should be something like the number of days since the 1 January 1900. 
How to get this in VBA ? In excel I'm getting this automatically when i concatenate a date with a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function dateToLong(ByVal d As Date) As Long

dateToLong = CLng(d)
End Function
```

If you need to capture the time in the long use this:

```
Function Dt2Lng(aDate As Date) As Long
   '-- acept datetime range from MinDate to
   '-- (MinDate + 49710 days + 6:28:15) ~ 136 years
   Dt2Lng = CLng((aDate - MinDate) * 86400 - 2 ^ 31)
End Function
```

Comment: Why do you create a date with `DateSerial` out of `d`, which is already a date? `CLng(d)` would suffice.

Comment: Upvote... as the acceptance of the answer (unfortunately) may be unlikely to happen =/

Answer (score 0):

Say if you have "1/1/2016" in A1, you could use Range("A1").Value2 to get the date serial number.